# How to fetch Layer Group with WMTS Service on GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wmts, group-layer

Is there a way to fetch Layer Group with WMTS service?
I fetch all layers as WMTS but when it comes to layer group, GeoServer throws 400 Bad request.
Here's my wmts uri for a single layer;

```
var data = [this.mapViewConfig.geoserverURL +
      '/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=workspace:s-layer&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL=0{x}&TILEROW={y}']
```

And this is what I tried for requesting group layer;

```
var data = [this.mapViewConfig.geoserverURL +
      '/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=workspace:layergroup&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL=0{x}&TILEROW={y}']
```

I added '**layergroup**' after **workspace:** but it returns 400 Bad Request.

Or how can I fetch layer group from GeoServer?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: is your layergroup in the workspace?

Comment: Yes, it is in the workspace @IanTurton